# Vanilla php files in subfolder with laravel - page not found error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a laravel app:  https://laravel-app.com

I want to serve custom pages from a folder on the same domain  https:laravel-app.com/player/player.php

I have set the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /player/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /player/player.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I try and navigate to that page by using this direct url:   https:laravel-app.com/player/player.php

I get the laravel routing error: sorry, the page could not be found

Can someone explain how to get around this?

Comment: is this `player` folder in laravel's `public` folder?

Comment: @lagbox  No, its in the root...but thats a good idea! Let me try this

Comment: @lagbox Hey man, can you make your comment the answer so i can accept it? It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you want accessible you can put in the `public` folder of your application, which should be the DocRoot/WebRoot. You won't need any special rewriting or rules as it will be an existing file so the server will serve it fine.